# Display User Info After Log In Post Request

Tags: flutter, post

I have the following POST request to Log an User:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/screens/homescreen/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter_easyloading/flutter_easyloading.dart';
import '../models/user_model.dart';

class HttpService {
  static const BASE_URL = "https://091a-186-249-214-216.ngrok.io";
  static const LOGIN_URL = "$BASE_URL/login";

  static Future<User> login(cpf, password, context) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(LOGIN_URL),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode({"cpf": cpf, "senha": password}),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      await Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      final user = User.fromJson(data);
      return user;
    } else {
      await EasyLoading.showError(
          "Error Code : ${response.statusCode.toString()}");
    }
    throw Exception('Failed to load User ID');
  }
}
```

And it returns a Class User which its code is:

```
class User {
  int id;
  String acessToken;
  String name;
  String cpf;
  String gender;
  String birthDate;
  String businessRole;
  String phoneNumber;
  String email;

  User({
    required this.acessToken,
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.cpf,
    required this.gender,
    required this.birthDate,
    required this.businessRole,
    required this.phoneNumber,
    required this.email,
  });

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      id: json['id'],
      acessToken: json['AcessToken'],
      name: json['Nome'],
      cpf: json['Cpf'],
      gender: json['Sexo'],
      birthDate: json['Data'],
      businessRole: json['Cargo'],
      phoneNumber: json['Numero'],
      email: json['Email'],
    );
  }
}
```

The JSON decoded response body is:

```
{
    "AcessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoxLCJleHAiOjE2ODc2Mzk5MjR9.NsdPaQM9w4GlAJQybKraiUf1pjcc9nM697PvU7MabkM",
    "Cargo": "Engenheiro Civil",
    "Cpf": "61308649304",
    "Data": "2018-12-03",
    "Email": "luigiskyline4@gmail.com",
    "Nome": "Luigi Gabriel Silva Gomes",
    "Numero": "99991974865",
    "Sexo": "masculino",
    "id": 1
}
```

As you can see, all data about user is provided after the POST request and then go to Homepage Screen. On this screen I want to show the User informations, as: id, name, etc. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using chatGPT to help me with some questions and solutions in flutter. About this problem, I found a way to pass the user to the Profile Screen by adding required parameters. There is the code:
1- Pass to HomeScreen's body:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final User user;
  const HomeScreen({super.key, required this.user});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       backgroundColor: grey1,
       body: Body(user: user),
      );
    }
  }
```

2- Pass to ProfileScreen:

```
class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
   int _index = 0;
   final List<Widget> screens = [];
   @override
   void initState() {
       screens.addAll([
         AgendaScreen(),
         MissoesScreen(),
         SuporteScreen(),
         ProfileScreen(user: widget.user),
    ]);
```

Then I just used user.id, user.name, etc. in profile screen to exhibit the user's details.

If anyone knows a better way to do it, please feel free to help me out.
Thanks! =)

Comment: When you say that you asked ChatGPT, I take it you tried this code and it worked for y